# not able to execute else part of this program in py

Tags: python

li = []

n = int(input("Enter numbers: "))

count = 0

for i in range(0,n):

```
a=int(input())
li.append(a)
```

print( li)

s = int(input('\nEnter a number for search : '))

for j in li:

```
if s == j:
    li.remove(j)
    count+=1
    if count == 1:
        print(f" {j} is removed . \n")
        break
    #else part is not executed
    else:
        print(f"Nothing is removed. \n")
```

print(li)

Comment: Please use code environment of markdown. By the way, you need to add comments about the error and what are your thinking please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the else statement belongs to the wrong if statement. Try moving the else statement back one indent. This will print `Nothing is removed` each time an element is not found.

```
for j in li:

    if s == j:
        li.remove(j)
        count+=1
        if count == 1:
            print(f" {j} is removed . \n")
            break
        #else part is not executed
    else:
        print(f"Nothing is removed. \n")
    print(li)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` statement you identified is not executed because it lines up with the `if count == 1:` statement above it.  Since `count` always equals 1 the first time through the loop and you `break` in the `if` statement, you exit the loop before `count` can be anything other than 1.

If you want the `else` statement to match the `if s == j:` statement then will have to outdent it.  Note, however, once you do that you will have other problems based on your loop logic, but hey, one thing at a time. ;^)